# "Version not found" when i trying to install something via npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

There is a problem, with npm.
When i trying to install something, i see this error. what's wrong? (Ubuntu 12.04)

root@server:~# sudo npm install bower -g

```
npm ERR! Error: version not found: bower : bower/bower
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:308:14)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:246:65)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1096:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-35-virtual
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Does this happen with you install anything or only when you're trying to install bower?

Comment: Also check your versions of `node` and `npm` to make sure they're up-to-date.

Comment: Anything and always this error

Comment: node - v0.10.35, npm - 1.4.28.

Comment: Your version of npm is kind of old.  You can update it with `npm install -g npm`

Comment: But how? :)
root@server:~# npm install -g npm
npm ERR! Error: version not found: npm : bower/npm

Comment: `curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` will re-install npm with the latest version

Comment: Yeah, now version is 2.1.18, but [seems like problem remains](https://gist.github.com/RevanScript/35094f3f1ee108d85a4b)

Comment: Fixed the problem with `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

ould you please upload your npm-debug.log as a  gist http://gist.github.com? If possible, run npm with at least one `-d` flag to increase the logging level.

There have been a lot of improvements to npm -- especially around conflicts and race conditions during install -- since 1.4.28. Can you try updating your npm installation?

To update npm, run `npm -g install npm@latest`

For some Linux distributions (Debian/Ubuntu and RedHat/CentOS), the latest node version provided by the distribution may lag behind the stable version. [Here are instructions from NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) on getting the latest node.

Thanks!